# How to get Javalin's Jetty http server to bind/listen on a specific address/port?

Tags: java, kotlin, jetty, embedded-jetty, javalin

Using `Javalin.create().port(portNumber)` sets the listen port, but it's unclear how to set the listen/bind address.

Comment: On a related note... The [github sample code here](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin-http2-example) helped me a great deal with similar questions relating to Jetty config for Javalin, including how to configure HTTP2 and TLS 1.3.

Answer (score 3):

Found out that you can create the Jetty Server instance yourself and configure it. In Kotlin:

```
    val port = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("PORT", "8080"))
    val jettyServer = JettyServerUtil.defaultServer()
    jettyServer.apply {
        connectors = arrayOf(ServerConnector(jettyServer).apply {
            this.host = System.getProperty("HOST", "0.0.0.0")
            this.port = port
        })
    }
    val app = Javalin.create()
            .port(port)
            .server { jettyServer }
            .start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do the same in Java:

```
int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("PORT", "8080"))
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server();
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
connector.setHost(System.getProperty("HOST", "0.0.0.0"));
connector.setPort(port);
server.setConnectors(new ServerConnector[] { connector });

Javalin app = Javalin.create(config -> {
    config.server(() -> server);
}).start(port);
```

Reference: https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/issues/138